# ORA-12518: TNS:listener could not hand off client connection

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

I am trying to create a new connection in my SQL Developer for a project for uni, and I get this error:

> Unable to connect to Oracle ORA-12518: TNS:listener could not hand off client connection.

I can connect to the user, add tables etc in SQL Plus, but I don't understand why I can't connect to the database in SQL Dev.

I tried to restart the listener, I verified that the data is entered correctly, and I verified that the listener runs on the server.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpbwY.png)

[image]

This is the content of my tns.ora file
[tns file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOcLu.png)

And this is the content of my listener.ora
[listener.ora](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQ4AF.png)

Comment: What does the working `SQL*Plus` connection look like?  My guess is that you have a working tnsnames.ora file entry that you're using in `SQL*Plus` and you should be using that same TNS alias in your SQL Developer connection

Comment: i updated my post with the contents of the listener and tns files, i use the exact port, host and service name but i still get the error

Answer (score 0):

If you are successfully using the `XE` TNS alias in `SQL*Plus`, you should be able to use the `XE` TNS alias in SQL Developer rather than trying to enter the same information in the SQL Developer connection string.  Choose a connection type of TNS to select the TNS alias you want to use.

If you want to configure the connection in SQL Developer separately from the TNS alias and you want to make that configuration match the current TNS alias configuration for `XE`, you'd need to list `xe` as the service name, not as the SID.